Difference between two terminal blocks
When I design PCBs, I normally come across two specific types of terminal blocks. The images of those terminal blocks are given below.

Amazon - REES52 30 Pcs 3.5mm Pitch 2 Pin PCB Mount Screw Terminal Block Connector, 2 pin terminal block, terminal block connector (https://www.amazon.in/REES52-Terminal-Connector-terminal-connector/dp/B08Z8C79TL)

DigiKey - 2 Position Wire to Board Terminal Block Horizontal with Board 0.200" (5.08mm) Through Hole (https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/phoenix-contact/1729128/260615)
In the blue terminal block, we can see a small metal strip is pressed down in the slots. In the green terminal block, a small hollow metal box is present which when I screw the terminal, the box comes to the top and holds the wire. What are the actual names of these two types of terminal blocks? In which cases, I should prefer one type over the other?


What are the actual names of these two types of terminal blocks? In
which cases, I should prefer one type over the other?

The second image shows a rising clamp arrangement.
Here's a view of the mechanism from this document: -

It's a surface mount connector but the idea is the same for through hole. It is superior to the first type as it provides a better grip for the wire.
I think the first image is a spring clamp.
